# CSV format issue

Tags: apex, csv

Here is the current code. I am expecting the 0000 value in my CSV file but it is printing only 0. Can anyone help with this?

```
fileRow = fileRow +','+ '"' +0000+ '"'; // Here I am expecting 0000 value in the CSV file instead it is printing the 0
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: When you write it like this, `0000` is interpreted as an integer, which is in turn converted to a string, which yields "0". Just change your line to `fileRow = fileRow + ',"0000"';`

Comment: I have tried with the syntax which you have recommended above. But still same problem resides.

Comment: Are you opening the file in Excel or something similar? If you use my method and open the file in a text editor it should show as four zeroes.

Comment: I am opening the file in the excel.

Comment: In that case, you should use this: `fileRow = fileRow + ',"\'0000"';`. I've prepended `'` this to the value, which should make it show as text in Excel. This will be useless for any other application that's supposed to consume the CSV though.

Comment: Thanks for the above syntax, which is working fine but we couldn't remove the prepended '. Because now in the CSV its displaying like this '0000